# Jest + Istanbul: collect coverage for functions called directly from the tests only

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage, istanbul

## Problem

Is there a way to configure Istanbul/Jest to collect a separate code coverage metric?

The metric should count the visited lines/branches of code but only when the line is executed as a part of a direct call to containing function.

## Motivation

I want to see how well are functions tested in isolation (in a true sense of unit-testing).

## Example

For the code below, I am interested in seeing the metric that counts every line of `foo()` function as visited once (since it is invoked directly from the test); however each `bar()`'s line to not be counted, because it's not invoked directly by the test, but rather called transitively.

```js
.
    // test.js       
    it(`should count things well`, () => {
      expect(foo()).toEqual(3);
    });
    
    // code.js
  | function foo() {
1 |   const a = 1;
1 |   const b = bar();
1 |   return a + b;
  | }

  | function bar() {
0 |   return 2;
  | }
```

## What I tried

The Istanbul-generated `coverage-final.json` does not seem to contain any metadata about *what* a certain line of code is. It only tells whether certain lines/branches of code are visited or not. I wonder if there are some command flags I could use to control what coverage information is being emitted and make an analysis of the extended data.

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for (so I won't say it's an "answer") but you could possibly mock everything by default (i.e. automock) then explicitly use the real function (i.e. requireActual) when you're testing it. If that works like I think it does you'll see zero coverage for functions that weren't called directly.